# How I do a select max(field) in Subsonic 3.0?

Tags: subsonic3

Yes, there is a method max with 13 overloads, none it's simply the name of the column.  Something can post an example in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VB.NET:  maxField = SomeTableClass.All().Max(Function(p As SomeTableClass) p.someField).
```

Is an option.  Using LINQ can be

```
(From x in SomeTableClass.All() select x.someField).Max()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Select max(coloumnName) from TableName)
```

...and you can add conditions or `order by` after this `select` statement.